# Get Keyboard events in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, keyboard-events, xlib

I want to write a program(for ubuntu OS) to play specific sounds for different characters pressed in perl.

When I searched in the google and found out that it has to deal with Xevents. I have also searched CPAN for the modules helpful for getting keyboard events.

The program should be able to play sound whenever the user types something, like in Ex: using console, editing in document, etc

I don't need any program to be written for me. All I need is information regarding the Modules and tips which will be useful.

Comment: have you tried `getc` ?

Comment: wait, you mean whichever screen he is on? then you will need to hook into the keyboard's "driver" or IRQ device

Comment: @nrathaus I mean whichever screen he is on. But I dont want to trap anything. Key press should be able to generate a sound and rest should be normal

Comment: @nrathaus Similar to `screenkey`. Instead of display, I need to play a sound.

Comment: maybe look at how http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/ does it? it is open source

Comment: @nrathaus Its Nice, I want to write a perl version

Answer (score 0):

There is a perl implementation of X11 protocol - [X11::Protocol](http://search.cpan.org/~smccam/X11-Protocol-0.56/Protocol.pm).

You need to use GrabKey/GrabKeyboard X11 requests